# Domain Driven Design. Entity type design

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have been trying to learn about DDD and entity and value types. I am querying the correct way to set value types from within an Entity type. In the below "Leader" class I have a "SetAddress" and "SetName" method, is this the correct way to update Value types from within an Entity type?

Also I have a List of PhoneNumbers, what is the recommended way to handle this? Should I just add a PhoneNumber to the list eg-

```
leader.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber("12345", Mobile);
```

Thanks for your help:

```
public class Leader:Entity
{
    public void SetName(string firstName, string surname)
    {
        Name = new Name(firstName, surname);
    }

    public Name Name { get; private set; } = Name.Empty;

    public void SetAddress(string street, string city, string postode)
    {
        Address = new AddressDetails(street, city, postode);
    }

    public AddressDetails Address { get; private set; } = AddressDetails.Empty;

    public List<Phone> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDetails : ValueObject<AddressDetails>
{
    public static readonly AddressDetails Empty = new AddressDetails(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);

    public AddressDetails(string street, string city, string postode)
    {
        Street = street;
        City = city;
        Postcode = postode;
    }

    public string Street { get; }
    public string City { get; }
    public string Postcode { get;  }

    protected override bool EqualsCore(AddressDetails other)
    {
        return Street == other.Street &&
            City == other.City &&
            Postcode == other.Postcode;
    }

    protected override int GetHashCodeCore()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = (hash * 23) ^ Street.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 23) ^ City.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 23) ^ Postcode.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a "SetAddress" and "SetName" method, is this the correct way to update Value types from within an Entity type?

It depends on what the business process being modelled is. In DDD you would typically name methods using word from the Ubiquitous Language. This example feels very CRUD-like. When you talk to the domain experts, what do they call the process?

Technically speaking, your example is one approach. Another would be to pass in the value objects directly to the methods, therefore exposing the concepts to callers of your API. i.e.

```
public void SetAddress(AddressDetails addressDetails)
{
    Address = addressDetails;
}
```

This way your domain is only dealing with domain concepts and callers of your API know what things are (i.e. an AddressDetails object, rather than some scalar values).

> Also I have a List of PhoneNumbers, what is the recommended way to handle this?

It depends if you want to expose the underlying storage mechanism, in this case, a List or not. Alternatively you could have methods like AddPhoneNumber(Phone phoneNumber) which would hide the fact that you are storing them in a List. If you ever change the underlying storage then the API might not need chaning. YMMV. Again, what is the business process being modelled? Is the list of phone numbers something that is a concept in the domain that should be exposed? Or is it just needed by some other process? (i.e. something like sending an SMS when an order is dispatched)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It all makes sense. It almost feels like I need a "PhoneList" or "PhoneCollection" type to handle the list of phone numbers.